# Add hover to a .live('click', function ()

Tags: jquery

This function shows **arrow-img-down** (a 'show' icon). When I click it open sliding div then the img turns **arrow-img-up** (a 'hide' icon)

I want to add to this img replace .src function and also a hover on current img as follows:

```
$(".showhide").live('click', function () {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "showhide") {
        this.src = this.src.replace("img/show_btn.png", "img/hide_btn.png");}
         else {
             this.src = this.src.replace("img/hide_btn.png", "img/show_btn.png");}

    $(this).toggleClass("img/show_btn.png");
});
```

How can I add it?

Comment: it better to use `hasClass` instead of `if ($(this).attr("class") == "showhide") {`

Comment: Note that the main reason `hasClass` should be used is because `$(this).attr("class") == …` will not work if you add a second class to an element.

Comment: The jquery site says that live is deprecated and on should be used instead. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.showhide').on('click hover', function (e) {
    // Your code here
    // Inside here you can use e.type to find out whether it was a
    // "click", "hover", "mouseup", etc...
});
```

Instead of `.on`, You can use `.bind` or `.live`. It's better to use `.on` since `.live` and `.bind` are being depreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an improved version of your code:

```
$( document ).on( 'click mouseenter mouseleave', '.showhide', function () {
    if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'showhide' ) ) {
        this.src = this.src.replace( 'img/show_btn.png', 'img/hide_btn.png' );
    } else {
        this.src = this.src.replace( 'img/hide_btn.png', 'img/show_btn.png' );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the hover word.

```
$(".showhide").live('click hover', function () {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "showhide") {
        this.src = this.src.replace("img/show_btn.png", "img/hide_btn.png");}
         else {
             this.src = this.src.replace("img/hide_btn.png", "img/show_btn.png");}

    $(this).toggleClass("img/show_btn.png");
});
```